# Calculate proximity in php

Tags: php, geolocation, distance, proximity

I am trying to write a php function that calculates proximity between two points but I cant get it to work.

I am currently using  a function found here: http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.php.html

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) { 

$theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
$dist = acos($dist); 
$dist = rad2deg($dist); 
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);

if ($unit == "m") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344)/1000; 
} 
else if ($unit == "N") {
  return ($miles * 0.8684);
} 
else {
    return $miles;
  }
}
```

---

My application requires precision down to meters but no matter what I do I dont get correct results.

I get the coordinates from here: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me out with this?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: How far off is your calculation from what you should be getting as a result? Is the error either arithmetically or geometrically consistent? Also, have you considered using a Geocoding API rather than rolling your own?

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: @Brian @arnorhs  Copying and pasting my code here I noticed that I was dividing by 1000 instead of multiplying to convert km to meters...changed that and it  seems to give good results but still dont know how to check this...@Brian could you maybe give me some details about a GEocoding API?? what would you recommend???

Comment: Google is your friend... in more ways than one: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this little class a while ago now, but it should help you with better distance calculations than the method in your question: https://github.com/treffynnon/Geographic-Calculations-in-PHP

To complete your question with the above link would be:

```
$Geography = new Geography();
echo $Geography->getDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2);
```

Will give the distance in metres using [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) for the distance calculation.

The Vincenty's formulae used in my class is a PHP port of the javascript function available at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/LatLongVincenty.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page with great detail on the algorithms available with JS examples:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html